# How to fix: Cannot find module '@entities/user' with custom paths?

Tags: nestjs

I would like to use custom paths from Typescript.

In my project, I switched from:

```
import { User } from 'src/entities/user.entity';
```

to:

```
import { User } from '@entities/user';
```

Into `tsconfig.json` I put :

```
"paths": {
  "@entities/*": ["src/entities/*.entity.ts"]
}
```

When I run `npm run start:dev` (=nodemon), I have this error:
`Error: Cannot find module '@entities/user'`

In debug mode, npm prints out:

```
looking for "@entities/user" in [".../node_modules", ".../node_modules"]
```

It is never looking for in the folder "src/entities" or something similar.

Maybe it is because thoses paths are not interpreted when running ? Should I create some kind of bootstrap like [here](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths#bootstraping-with-explicit-params) ?

FIX

The issue came from `nodemon.json`:

I had to replace:

```
{
  "watch": ["dist"],
  "ext": "js",
  "exec": "node dist/main"
}
```

By:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts"
}
```

Now TypeORM knows where to find the entities in development env.

Comment: Can you show ```tsconfig.json```?

Comment: I have found the bug thank you. FYI
```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@modules/*": [
        "src/modules/*.module.ts",
      ],
      "@entities/*": [
        "src/entities/*.entity.ts",
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

FIX

The issue came from nodemon.json:

I had to replace:

```
{
  "watch": ["dist"],
  "ext": "js",
  "exec": "node dist/main"
}
```

By:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts"
}
```

Now TypeORM knows where to find the entities in development env.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction when trying to get Mocha Test Explorer to work: I needed to add `tsconfig-paths/register` to the `mochaExplorer.require` property in VSCode's settings.json.